# Visual C++ in VS 2017 hiding values of member variables in Debug mode

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

After adding a member variable to a class, and then running some code that uses it, the debugger hides information about this member variable. I'm in Debug mode not release mode and not optimizing away anything.

Ex:

```
class Rect {
    float width; <--- existing
    float height; <-- new variable, values do not show
}
```

When debugging a value using this, the value of height will be hidden away (or show an incorrect value). If I store this in a local variable, then it gets displayed correctly. I have not seen this happening in Visual Studio 2013 which I was using before switching to 2017. I'm on update 15.9.1

Comment: I would try a clean build. Also make sure you don't have more than 1 class Rect defined.

Comment: VS2017 is always broken in one way or another.  Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to let them know about this quirk.  After updating it and checking that this still happens, 15.x.y versions have a lot of agile bugs when y is still low.